# Extract a particular element from a list of acf outputs

Tags: r, extract, autocorrelation

I output a series of `acf` results and want to extract just lag 1 autocorrelation coefficient. Can anyone give a quick pointer? Thank you.

```
#A snippet of a series of acf() results
$`25`

Autocorrelations of series ‘x’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12 
 1.000  0.366 -0.347 -0.399 -0.074  0.230  0.050 -0.250 -0.213 -0.106  0.059  0.154  0.031 

$`26`

Autocorrelations of series ‘x’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
 1.000  0.060  0.026 -0.163 -0.233 -0.191 -0.377  0.214  0.037  0.178 -0.016  0.049 

$`27`

Autocorrelations of series ‘x’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12 
 1.000 -0.025 -0.136  0.569 -0.227 -0.264  0.218 -0.262 -0.411  0.123 -0.039 -0.192  0.130 
#For this example, the extracted values will be 0.366, 0.060, -0.025, the values can either 
be in a list or matrix
```

**EDIT**

```
#`acf` in base R was used  
p <- acf.each() 
#sapply was tried but it resulted this 
sapply(acf.each(), `[`, "1")
          1             2             3                  
acf    0.7398        0.1746        0.4278              
type   "correlation" "correlation" "correlation" 
n.used    24            17            14                 
lag       1             1             1                     
series    "x"          "x"           "x"                       
snames   NULL          NULL          NULL
```

Comment: If @akrun's solution don't work for you, please provide additional details about what package you are using (`nmle`?) and which method is being used.

Comment: @IanCampbell Thank you. More details were added. Only `acf()` in base R was used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure seems to be a `list`.  We can use `sapply` to do the extraction

```
sapply(lst1, function(x) x$acf[2])
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(acf(ldeaths), acf(ldeaths))
```